# Color US states according to value in R

Tags: r, dictionary, colors, maps, state

In R, I want to color the US states by value.
I have my data in a table like this:

```
    AK  0.1511529
    AL  0.1720370
    AR  0.2078534
    AZ  0.2057174
```

etc.

How do I do this in a simple way? I have tried using

```
    maps("state"),
```

but that gives me state names that do not correspond to the state abbreviations:

```
"alabama"
"arizona"
```

and things like

```
"washington:orcas island"
```

I feel like there should be a simplere solution than trying to match them up using

```
 state.abb
 state.name
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider posting the code you have tried so others can run it and modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching isn't a bad solution. I hope this code example helps.

```
# your values (here as named vector)
values <- runif(length(state.abb),0,1)
names(values) <- state.abb

# getting the names used by map
tmp <- map('state',plot=FALSE,namesonly=TRUE)
# matching (after adjusting using gsub and tolower)
tmp <- match(gsub('(:.*)','',tmp),tolower(state.name))
# convert your numbers to grey-scale and selct using the match
map('state',fill=TRUE,col=grey(values)[tmp])
```

The matching is necessary, also because there may be more than one polygon to draw per state.